# How to fix the error when occurred Installing updates of maven to eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

When Im trying to install a maven plugin to my eclipse, Following error occurred.
I'm using windows 8 64 bits and Im using eclipse helios for java ee.
I've install the following maven to my eclipse.
http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases

This was the error I had get,

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.4.1.20140328-1905 (org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group 1.4.1.20140328-1905)
  Missing requirement: Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.4.1.20140328-1905 (org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui 1.4.1.20140328-1905) requires 'bundle org.slf4j.api 1.6.2' but it could not be found

I will grateful to you if youhelp me to solve this problem.
thanks
regards 
kaushi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use the latest stable version of eclipse

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/kepler/R/eclipse-jee-kepler-R-win32-x86_64.zip

Install a maven separately. And point the the maven in eclipse using the 'external' way.

Running maven in command line is more trust worthy than eclipse maven build given m2e has bugs.